# Integrating piecewise function in two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I want to find (and plot) the integral of a 'smooth' version of the Möbius function `MoebiusMu[x]`:

```
bump[x_, a_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(Cos[2*Pi*x] + 1)/2, x - 1/2 < a < x + 1/2}, 
     {0, True}}]; 
bumpmob[x_, b_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[a]*bump[x, a], {a, 1, b}]; 
Show[DiscretePlot[MoebiusMu[a], {a, 25}], Plot[{bumpmob[x, 25]}, 
 {x, 0, 25}], GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I would like to integrate this function, but I'm not sure what syntax to use. Everything I try just seems to leave Mathematica evaluating without end - I suspect it's to do with either the fact that `MoebiusMu[x]` is a discrete function on integers only, or to do with having two variables.

I realise that this probably a very basic question (I have seen similar but much more complex questions on this site, but couldn't quite follow what was going on). Suggestions?

Comment: Many definitions are missing from that code. What's MoebiusMu what's mob1 what's units

Comment: OP now edited. Apologies - cut and pasted the wrong thing. `MoebiusMu[x]` is the built-in expression for the Möbius function.

Comment: Probably you want :`NIntegrate` ?

Comment: Hmmm. What I'd really like is a piecewise general integral rather than a partial integral between specified values...

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Integrate[bumpmob[x, 25], x]
```

Comment: Hi @Ulrich, that just produces the 'S'-sign image of the integral...

Comment: What means "'S'-sign image of the integral" ?

Comment: It produces the standard symbol used in maths to mean 'integrate'. In other words,  Mathematica evaluates `Integrate[bumpmob[x, 25], x]` as `Integrate[bumpmob[x, 25], x]//TraditionalForm`...

Comment: It is the `Antiderivative` of bumpmob, I think. And you are looking for what???